# How to serverside read Google indexed pages number by "site:www.example.com"?

Tags: php, google-api, seo, google-search

The point is to get number of indexed pages in Google using "site:" query.

I've been trying to use

```
https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=*******&cx=****&q=site:www.example.com
```

but this Custom Search does not return accurate values (10% of real index, checked in browser search).

Old API works perfectly:

```
ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=site:www.example.com
```

But it doesn't work anymore :/

```
{"responseData": null, "responseDetails": "The Google Web Search API is no longer available. Please migrate to the Google Custom Search API (https://developers.google.com/custom-search/)", "responseStatus": 403}
```

Any idea how to do it?